# Looping over an objects in a array and create separate tables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, ecmascript-6

Please help me create three different tables based on the region name, each table could have multiple fields based on data from backend. basically I need to create a title as region name and group all details as per region name.

For example:

Title of table:

```
New York
name | age
bob    26

chicago
name | age
bob    26
mick   25
```

Here is my array:

```
var details = [
  {
    "region": "chicago",
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 26
  },
  {
    "region": "chicago",
    "name": "mick",
    "age": 25 
  },{
    "region": "new york",
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 21,
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "region": "new jersey",
    "name": "gen",
    "age":22  
  },
  {
    "region": "new york",
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 29,
    "hobby": "ps"
  }  
]
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: I tried with map, but no luck yet! Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: When you say "table", what do you mean?  There's no data structure in Javascript called a table so I'm not sure what you mean.  Are you talking about a table in HTML in the browser DOM?

Comment: create a table with details based on region, like for example whoever is in chicago, there details come under one table.

Comment: So, you mean an HTML table in the browser page?  There's nothing in your question that makes it clear that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I get the posted data and I need to create tables as per region name. who all are in one region, there details will be mentioned in one html table,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, (from the supplied data example) column names can be dynamic, the problem with that is that to construct a table from such data you need to know possible columns ahead, which basically means iterating over data twice.

```
var tables = {}, columns = [];

// first extract all possible column names, excluding region ofcourse
details.forEach((detail) => {
  Object.keys(detail).forEach((column) => {
    if (column !== "region" && columns.indexOf(column) === -1) {
      columns.push(column);
    }
  });
});

// then iterate over data and construct table rows
details.forEach((detail) => {
  var table = tables[detail.region] || (tables[detail.region] = []), row = {};
  columns.forEach((column) => row[column] = detail[column])
  table.push(row);
});

// after data has been grouped into tables just create simple table
// and add data rows.
$.each(tables, (regionName, rows) => {
  var table = $("<table/>");
  var regionNameRow = $("<tr/>");
  var columnsRow = $("<tr/>");
  var regionNameTh = $("<th colspan='" + columns.length + "'>" + regionName + "</td>");


  columns.forEach((column) => {
    columnsRow.append($("<th>").html(column));
  });

  regionNameRow.append(regionNameTh);
  table.append(regionNameRow);
  table.append(columnsRow);

  rows.forEach((row) => {
    var tableRow = $("<tr/>");
    $.each(row, (columnName, value) => {
      tableRow.append($("<td>").html(value || "-"));
    });
    table.append(tableRow);
  });


  $("#container").append(table);
  $("#container").append("<hr/>");
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the result https://jsfiddle.net/okqbq4r2/18/

Also you might need to added additional filtering step if you wish to exclude empty columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this tho extract the data

```
var chicagoList = details.map(function(x) {

  if (x.region === 'chicago') {
      return {
        "name": x.name,
        "age": x.age
      };
    }
  });
```

Comment: we don't know the region name unless we map, its not always same regions

Comment: Is just an example... you could do a map of arrays whith the regions found

Answer (score 0):

So my answer might be a little long winded but you can go through the array, grab the unique regions, create tables dynamically and then append rows based on matching regions.  Not the most elegant but it will get the job done. Code below and working jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/brockdavis008/b69g3w3p/

```
$(function(){
 CreateTables();
})

function CreateTables(){
var uniqueRegions = []
$.each(details,function(index,item){
    if (($.inArray(item.region, uniqueRegions)) == -1){
  uniqueRegions.push(item.region);
  }
})
$.each(uniqueRegions,function(index,item){
var regionname = item.replace(" ","");
$("#data").append("<table id='"+regionname+"region'><th>Name</th><th>Age</th>")
});

$.each(details,function(index,item){
var tr = "<tr><td>"+item.name+"</td><td>"+item.age+"</td></tr>";
var regionname = item.region.replace(" ","");
$("#"+regionname+"region").append(tr)

})
}

var details = [
  {
    "region": "chicago",
    "name": "bob",
    "age": 26
  },
  {
    "region": "chicago",
    "name": "mick",
    "age": 25 
  },{
    "region": "new york",
    "name": "tom",
    "age": 21,
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "region": "new jersey",
    "name": "gen",
    "age":22  
  },
  {
    "region": "new york",
    "name": "mike",
    "age": 29,
    "hobby": "ps"
  }  
]
```

Comment: thank you I will try that out and can you pleas elet me know how to get title of table as each region.

Comment: If you look at my code I create an array for unique regions then create tables with the id of [regionname]region which in this example would create three tables, chicagoregion newyorkregion and newjerseyregion.  Then I go through the entire array and append the row to the tables that match it

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the `details` first into an array that has objects segregated into regions.

```js
const details = [{
  "region": "chicago",
  "name": "bob",
  "age": 26
}, {
  "region": "chicago",
  "name": "mick",
  "age": 25
}, {
  "region": "new york",
  "name": "tom",
  "age": 21,
  "status": "active"
}, {
  "region": "new jersey",
  "name": "gen",
  "age": 22
}, {
  "region": "new york",
  "name": "mike",
  "age": 29,
  "hobby": "ps"
}];

const tableDetails = details.reduce((arr, item) => {
  const isRegionExisting = arr.some((detail) => detail.region === item.region);
  let region;

  if (isRegionExisting) {
    region = arr.find((detail) => detail.region === item.region);
  } else {
    region = { region: item.region, people: [] };
    arr.push(region);
  }

  region.people.push({
    name: item.name,
    age: item.age,
  });

  return arr;
}, []);

tableDetails.forEach(generateTable);

function generateTable({ region, people }) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  const caption = table.appendChild(document.createElement('caption'));
  const thead = table.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
  const theadRow = thead.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
  const tbody = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tbody'));

  caption.innerText = region;

  Object.keys(people[0]).forEach((key) => {
    const th = theadRow.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));

    th.innerText = key;
  });

  people.forEach((person) => {
    const tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

    Object.values(person).forEach((value) => {
      const td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));

      td.innerText = value;
    });
  });

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1.8 normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 10px 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

caption, th {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}

tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```